# Using the result of a macro/command in FPEval / Undefined Control Sequence

Tags: fp

How can the following LaTeX code be fixed to use the result of "\RoundGrade{\codeA}" correctly in a later \FPEval computation?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fp}

\newcommand{\RoundGrade}[1]{\FPiflt{#1}{1.15001}1.0\else1.3\fi}

\begin{document}
\FPeval{\codeA}{1.03}%
Rounded to \RoundGrade{\codeA}
\FPeval{\codeB}{+(\RoundGrade{\codeA},0)}
\end{document}
```

Expected behavior is that "\codeB" contains "1.0" at the time the (pdf)LaTeX compiler hits "\end{document}". Rather, the code currently yields:

```
/path/to/texfile.tex:9: Undefined control sequence.
\FP@strip #1->{\edef \FP@tmp {#1}\edef \FP@tmpb 
                                                {}\ifx \FP@tmp \@empty \else...
l.9 \FPeval{\codeB}{+(\RoundGrade{\codeA},0)}
```

When replacing "\RoundGrade{\codeA}" by "1.0" in the second-to-last line above, the document compiles. Also, the value 1.0 is printed in the resulting document correctly in the third-to-last line (when commenting out the second-to-last line).

Comment: instead of the fp package you could use the inbuilt \fpeval: `\newcommand\codeA{1.03}\edef\codeB{\fpeval{\codeA < 1.15001 ?1.0:1.3}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! Interestingly, using \fpeval instead of \FPiflt in the definition of \RoundGrade makes everything work (I really wanted this to be a macro/function in the actual document). It would be great to get an insight why that is the case.

Comment: the in-built code (in the L3 Layer/ expl3) is expandable and so works in an \edef. See here for an overview https://www.texdev.net/2018/12/09/floating-point-calculations-in-latex